# How to clear a readable stream while uploading image in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to upload multiple images with the help of multiparty module. I want to upload only a particular kind of images, say whose names are 'image.jpg'. But it's not working when the image does not meet the criteria and I don't get any response. Here is my code.

```
req.form.on('part', function(part) {
    if (part.filename === 'image.jpg') {
        var out = fs.createWriteStream('image/' + part.filename);
        part.pipe(out);
    } else {
        //Here i want to clear the stream for the next 'part'
    }
});
req.form.on('close', function() {
    res.send('uploaded!');
});
```

I think I'm not able to clear the readable stream which contains 'part'. I can write that stream and then delete, it works then. But, I don't want to write any image on my file system if it doesn't meet the criteria. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complete robertklep's answer, here is another possibility using a custom [Writable stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable) that will blackhole data. When you `pipe()` the `part` stream to the blackhole, it will exhaust its source. This just keeps your code consistent by using streams everywhere instead of using raw `read()` function calls.

```
req.form.on('part', function(part) {
  var out;
  if (part.filename === 'image.jpg') {
    out = fs.createWriteStream('image/' + part.filename);
  } else {
    out = new stream.Writable();
    out._write = function (chunk, encoding, done) {
      done(); // Don't do anything with the data
    };
  }
  part.pipe(out);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure if this is going to work, but I think you can read the entire `part` stream until it's exhausted:

```
req.form.on('part', function(part) {
    if (part.filename === 'image.jpg') {
        var out = fs.createWriteStream('image/' + part.filename);
        part.pipe(out);
    } else {
        while (part.read() !== null);
    }
});
```